# Could not ping secondary interface private IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have attached a secondary interface to Debian EC2 instance. I attached the same security group that primary interface has and it allows ping on it.
Problem is after attaching the second network interface I am not able to ping the Secondary interface private IP.

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0a:65:1c:fd:cd:f0  
          inet addr:10.195.0.76  Bcast:10.195.0.95  Mask:255.255.255.224
          inet6 addr: fe80::865:1cff:fefd:cdf0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:9001  Metric:1
          RX packets:1494 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1158 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:164133 (160.2 KiB)  TX bytes:185670 (181.3 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0a:2d:a1:fc:f5:d4  
          inet addr:10.195.0.82  Bcast:10.195.0.95  Mask:255.255.255.224
          inet6 addr: fe80::82d:a1ff:fefc:f5d4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:9001  Metric:1
          RX packets:274 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:46 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:24474 (23.9 KiB)  TX bytes:2948 (2.8 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Ngrep result pinging from other interface:

```
root@ip-10-195-0-76:/home/admin# ngrep -d eth1 -Wbyline
interface: eth1 (10.195.0.64/255.255.255.224)
#
I fe80::81a:8eff:fe7b:e6a9 -> ff02::1 134:0
@.............
..{....@.............*....to.........
#
I 10.195.1.30 -> 10.195.0.82 8:0
\......[.....X
..................... !"#$%&'()*+,-./01234567
#
I 10.195.1.30 -> 10.195.0.82 8:0
\......[......
..................... !"#$%&'()*+,-./01234567
```

Comment: From where do you ping?

Comment: I am trying from other instance in the same subnet.

Answer (score 0):

Debian in AWS does provide ec2-net-utils but the scripts on EC2 does not add the routes for the secondary interface. To solve this i followed the following to add the routes for the interface.

```
#echo "200 out" >>/etc/iproute2/rt_tables
# ip route add default via 10.195.0.65 dev eth1 table out
#ip route show table out
#ip rule add from 10.195.0.82/32 table out
#ip rule add to 10.195.0.82/32 table out
```

And after that i am able ping the network interface.